# Angular 2: disable button if there are changes in form

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, field, angular-forms

I want to check if *at least one field in my form is changed*. If this scenario is true, the `disableButton` will be set to **true**, and **false** if there are *no changes* in the form. Below is my current code:

```
// this.hold is an array that temporary holds the previous values of 
// the form for comparison of the changes in form

if(this.data.process == 'update') {
   for(const f in form.value){
       if (form.value[f] == this.hold[f])
           this.disableButton = true;
       else
           this.disableButton = false;
   }
}
```

The problem is, the button only disables when **ALL** fields are
changed. What should I add in my condition or in for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a break when you find that a value is changed.

```
if(this.data.process == 'update') {
   for(const f in form.value){
       if (form.value[f] == this.hold[f]){
           this.disableButton = true;

       }    
       else{
          this.disableButton = false;
          break;
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: you were setting it to true when the values are same , which is the opposite of what you want , i have changed the code, try now

Comment: You need not to change the boolean. But this worked. Thanks @YounisArM

Answer (score 5):

Angular tracks form controls values and sets the status to `dirty` if any of them has changed. You don't need to manually check each control. Just use `.dirty` property of the form:

```
this.disableButton = form.dirty;
```

If you want to exclude "backtracking" - adding and then removing something, you can use `markAsPristine()` method to set control to `pristine` state when the value that changed is the same as it was initially. You can have the object of initial values:

```
const initialValues = {prop: 3};
form.valueChanges.subscribe((changes)=>{
    for (prop in changes) {
       if (changes[prop] === initialValues[prop]) {
           form.get(prop).markAsPristine();
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: but what if user deletes changes, it would still be dirty right @Maximus

Comment: do you mean if there was the value `a` and then the user added `b` so it's `ab` now and then removed `b` and `a` is left as it was before the change?

Comment: It's dirty yes, but you can add a "Reset" button to call the `.reset()` function on the `NgForm` object to reset the state to pristine again, if that suits your needs. If you must allow the user to manually return to the initial state then I'm afraid you'll have to compare each field manually...

Comment: @Char, @Amit `setPrisine()` method is even better alternative

Comment: I think `setPristine` is the angularjs name, I think angular2/4 uses `markAsPristine` but I wouldn't use it since you'd have to manually decide whether it's the same value as before, I still think reset is a better option.

Comment: yeah, it's `markAsPrisine()`. Also how `reset` will help to *not* _decide whether it's the same value as before_?

Comment: @Char, the way you do it is logically incorrect and the answer you accepted  just helped you implement incorrect approach. You will now have the control thinking it's dirty while other system thinks it's pristine. At least add `markAsPristine()` to your code

Comment: Good answer, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `pristine` property (or the inverse `dirty` property) is what you're after. It's defined on the [`AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) class, and indicates whether any changes have been made to your `FormControl`, `FormGroup` or `FormArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
editForm: FormGroup;
    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      editCountry: ['', Validators.required],
      editDate: ['', Validators.required],
      editHolidayName: ['', Validators.required],
    });
     <div>
    <button [disabled]="!editForm.dirty" type="button" class="btn btn-primary miracle-submit m-t-5">Save</button>
    </div>
```